# Identifying the whitespaces string in android

Tags: android, string, kotlin, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I have a series of strings where I have to identify the strings having only white spaces. Following is the regex that I have used, but it is returning only false.

```
  private fun isOnlySpaces(deviceFriendlyName: String) : Boolean{
        val whiteSpaces = Pattern.compile("/^\\s+\$/")
        return whiteSpaces.matcher(deviceFriendlyName).matches()
    }
```

Could you please let me know how to identify whitespaces without using isEmpty().

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to use regex for this. Use [CharSequence.isBlank()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/is-blank.html) method for verifying whitespaces presence.

Note that `isBlank()` method will return true when the string you are verifying is empty. If such behaviour is not expected you can always write your own extension function that takes string length into consideration:

```kotlin
fun CharSequence.allWhitespace(): Boolean = 
    length > 0 && indices.all { this[it].isWhitespace() }
```

And then use it your code

```kotlin
if (deviceFriendlyName.allWhitespace()) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: You could do `= !isEmpty() && isBlank()` if you just want to avoid handing empty strings (or `isNullOrEmpty()` if you want to handle nullables too). Good candidate for a property instead of a function too! Like `val CharSequence.isWhitespace get() = !isEmpty() && isBlank() `

Answer (score 0):

The regex you used is not correct, it contains this character `/`, this should be removed, here is the right regex:

```
private fun isOnlySpaces(deviceFriendlyName: String) : Boolean{
    val whiteSpaces = Pattern.compile("^\\s+$")
    return whiteSpaces.matcher(deviceFriendlyName).matches()
}
```